# finding the checksum

Tags: networking, network-programming, binary, udp, checksum

We have three 16-bit words:

```
0110011001100000
0101010101010101
1000111100001100
```

sum of the first two

```
0110011001100000
0101010101010101
-----------------
1011101110110101
```

adding the sum to the third

```
1000111100001100
1011101110110101
-------------------
10100101011000001
```

but the book says for that part that it's:

```
0100101011000010
```

It says that the last addition had overflow which was wrapped around but i don't understand.

After that it obtains the 1st complement:

```
1011010100111101
```

which becomes the checksum.

I don't understand the adding the sum to the third part. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's adding the sum to the third value.

Note the indentation. The overflow bit is the *leftmost* bit.

```
 1000111100001100
 1011101110110101
-----------------
10100101011000001
^
```

Add the overflow to the truncated result:

```
 0100101011000001
 0000000000000001
-----------------
 0100101011000010
```

Which is the desired result for that step.