# Why we need wraparound in UPD checksum algorithm?

Tags: network-programming, udp, checksum

I kown how [UDP algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391991/finding-the-checksum) working.
In this algorithm, if the last addition had overflow which was `wrapped around:

```
 1000111100001100
 1011101110110101
-----------------
10100101011000001
^
```

Add the overflow to the truncated result:

```
0100101011000001
 0000000000000001
-----------------
 0100101011000010
```

But I don't know why it must need `the wraparound operation` in this algorithm. Is there any advantage to `wraparound operation`?

Comment: not sure what you mean. But you realize that the checksum is 16bit only, so you need to handle a potential overflow?

Comment: UDP. The term is UDP. Not UPD. Be precise. And you don’t  need to say everything twice. Twice.

Comment: And the answer to your question is ‘because that’s what it says in the RFC’.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich  Sorry for wasting your time.I change my question， I would like to know why `wrap around` is needed and does it do any good? Or is it just used by the RFC.

Comment: Why don’t you fix your typos when you edit your question?